# What is the best approach for assigning permissions to groups of users in abp framework

Tags: .net, .net-core, abp, abp-framework

As we work with user permissions, a common scenario arises: assigning permissions to a group of users rather than individual users. This scenario is essential for managing access control efficiently.

What is the recommended approach within the ABP Framework when dealing with permissions for groups of users? Should we utilize organization units or explore alternative methods for assigning permissions to user groups?

- We currently manage permissions at the user and role levels.

- Requirement: Assign permissions to a defined group of users, allowing all members within that group to inherit these permissions.

- Seeking guidance on the most effective and standardized method within the framework for managing permissions at this granularity.

Potential Solutions Explored:

Utilizing organization units: Assessing the suitability of organization units for grouping users and managing permissions.

Our aim is to determine the most effective way to assign permissions to groups of users, ensuring scalability, maintainability, and adherence to best practices within the framework's authorization system.

Thank you for your input and guidance on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Organization Units (OU) are used to hierarchically group users and entities. Therefore, it would be a good solution for your requirements.

First, you can create a role and grant all related permissions that you want. Then, you can create an OrganizationUnit from the UI, group the related users in it, and set the role that you defined, so the users would inherit the related roles from the OrganizationUnit and all of them would have the related permissions.

[image]

Also, you can easily manage with this approach, add-remove organization units from a specific user or see which roles are inherited from OU:

[image]